# Using python argparser, is there a way to specify that out of two args, only 1 can be provided

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input, argparse

Usecase:

I am using python [argparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) and collecting user input as arguments.

Suppose user is allowed to provide input for arguments `foo` and `bar`.
I want to restrict it, saying user can either provide values for argument foo or bar, not for both at the same time.

Sample code:

```py
import argparse

my_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
my_parser.add_argument('foo',
                       help='xxxxxxxxxxx')
my_parser.add_argument('bar',
                       help='xxxxxxxxxxx')
args = my_parser.parse_args()

print(vars(args))
```

Is this possible directly in argparser? Or do i need to handle this in my python code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
my_group = my_parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=False)
my_group.add_argument('foo', help='xxxxxxxxxxx')
my_group.add_argument('bar', help='xxxxxxxxxxx')
```

Set `required` as appropriate.  I chose `false` based on your wording that "user can either provide values for argument foo or bar, not for both."